# Why are inverses of permutations in the formula for $det(A^T)$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

This question stems from proving $det(A^T)=det(A)$ with the definition of determinants with permutation.

Define $det(A)=\sum_\sigma sign(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i\sigma(i)}$ where $\sigma$ goes through the permutations of $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Then we have that $det(A^T)=\sum_{\sigma} sign(\sigma^{-1})\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma^{-1}(i)i}$.

Why is it that the inverse of $\sigma$ is used for the determinant of the transpose? And also the following equality is true right?

$det(A^T)=\sum_{\sigma} sign(\sigma^{-1})\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma^{-1}(i)i}=\sum_{\sigma} sign(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i)i}$. So can't we just switch the $i$ with $\sigma(i)$ for $a$ in the definition to get the transpose, whats the point of involving inverses?

Comment: I do not think you want to prove that $A=A^T$ ... but rather that their determinant is equal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition for an $n\times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$
$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma}(-1)^{\sigma}a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}\tag{1}$$
If we write $A^T=(\tilde{a}_{ij})$, then substituting $A^T$ for $A$ in (1) yields
$$\det(A^T)=\sum_{\sigma}(-1)^{\sigma}\tilde{a}_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots \tilde{a}_{n\sigma(n)}\tag{2}$$
But $\tilde{a}_{ij}=a_{ji}$ by definition of $A^T$, so this just says
$$\det(A^T)=\sum_{\sigma}(-1)^{\sigma}a_{\sigma(1)1}\cdots a_{\sigma(n)n}\tag{3}$$
In order to connect (3) to (1), we observe that
$$a_{\sigma(1)1}\cdots a_{\sigma(n)n}=a_{1\sigma^{-1}(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma^{-1}(n)}\tag{4}$$
Using (3) and (4), the fact that $(-1)^{\sigma}=(-1)^{\sigma^{-1}}$, and the fact that $\sigma^{-1}$ ranges over all permutations as $\sigma$ does, we obtain that $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$.

In summary, $\sigma^{-1}$ naturally arises when we try to connect (3) and (1).

Comment: thanks this helped me.